# How to convert combined spacy ner tags to BIO format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

How can I convert this into BIO format? I have tried using spacy `biluo_tags_from_offsets` but it's failing to catch all entities and I think I know the reason why.

```
tags = biluo_tags_from_offsets(doc, annot['entities'])
```

BSc(Bachelor of science) - These two are combined together but spacy split the text when there is a space. So now the words will be like ( `BSc(Bachelor, of, science` ) and this is why spacy `biluo_tags_from_offsets` failing  and return `-`

Now, when it checks for `(80, 83, 'Degree')` It can't find BSc word alone. Similarly it will again fail for `(84, 103, 'Degree')`.

How can I fix these scenarios? Please help if anyone can.

---

```
EDUCATION: · Master of Computer Applications (MCA) from NV, *********, *****. · BSc(Bachelor of science) from NV, *********, *****

{'entities': [(13, 44, 'Degree'), (46, 49, 'Degree'), (80, 83, 'Degree'), (84, 103, 'Degree')]}
```

Comment: Can you try combining tokens with `Doc.retokenize()` like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63982729/4317058 ? It's interesting to see if pretrained model will still recognize new combined tokens.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov Can you provide a working example, I was not able to understand it properly from that link, what exactly that retokenize does()

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I read online, that spacy does not support overlapping entities? Is there any way I can solve these problems. I was not able to find any good articles with a working example on how to tackle these issue? If you are familiar please help me out.

Comment: You may also wish to check this out https://spacy.io/api/pipeline-functions#merge_entities

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov  I have read it while researching. But in my case the overlapping entities are two different labels. How can I merge two entities onto a single word? I'm not being able to understand how to build a ner around it. If you are familiar with the work flow please help me out. I'm stuck at it for weeks now. My dataset has two issue, one is I listed above another one is overlapping entities.

Comment: Please think about presenting a [reprex] with input data and desired output.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you pass your data into `biluo_tags_from_offsets(doc, entities)`, where `entities` are like `[(14, 44, 'ORG'), (51, 54, 'ORG')]`. You can edit this param as you wish (you can start with editing `doc.ents` and proceed from there as well). You may add, remove, combine any entities in this list like in below example:

```
import spacy
from spacy.gold import biluo_tags_from_offsets
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")

text = "I have a BSc (Bachelors of Computer Sciences) from NYU"
doc = nlp(text)
print("Entities before adding new entity:", doc.ents)

entities = []
for ent in doc.ents:
    entities.append((ent.start_char, ent.end_char, ent.label_))
print("BILUO before adding new entity:", biluo_tags_from_offsets(doc, entities))

entities.append((9,12,'ORG')) # add a desired entity

print("BILUO after adding new entity:", biluo_tags_from_offsets(doc, entities))

Entities before adding new entity: (Bachelors of Computer Sciences, NYU)
BILUO before adding new entity: ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-ORG', 'I-ORG', 'I-ORG', 'L-ORG', 'O', 'O', 'U-ORG']
BILUO after adding new entity: ['O', 'O', 'O', 'U-ORG', 'O', 'B-ORG', 'I-ORG', 'I-ORG', 'L-ORG', 'O', 'O', 'U-ORG']
```

If you want the process of merging entities to be rule based you can try [entityruler](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#entityruler) with the following simplified example (taken from above link):

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler

nlp = English()
ruler = EntityRuler(nlp)
patterns = [{"label": "ORG", "pattern": "Apple"},
            {"label": "GPE", "pattern": [{"LOWER": "san"}, {"LOWER": "francisco"}]}]
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
nlp.add_pipe(ruler)

doc = nlp("Apple is opening its first big office in San Francisco.")
print([(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents])
```

and then again pass the list of redefined (merged in your case) entities to `biluo_tags_from_offsets`, like in the first code snippet

Comment: @user_12 Does it answer your question? Was it helpful? Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers